# Construction of a metric from a "topological" measure

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Is there a way to construct (perhaps cannonical) a metric from a measure on Borel sets of a Hausdorff topological space? I know of theorems regarding topological spaces inducing measures, such as the Haar measure theorem and Riesz-Markov-Kakutani theorem. My question, is are there theorems regarding "the other" direction of constructing a metric from say a Radon measure on a Hausdorff first countable locally compact space.

I saw somewhere where they said that the hyperbolic measure $\dfrac{dxdy}{y^2}$ induces the hyperbolic distance, and I was wondering whether there is a standard construction that I am oblivious to.

Comment: Every compact group has Haar measure. But not all of them are metrizable, e.g. the uncountable product $(S^1)^\mathfrak{c}$.

Comment: Is there a theorem with  perhaps much more demanding conditions relating a Radon measure on a locally compact normal space and a construction to a metric?

Comment: I'm more interested with a canonical construction of a metric from a measure, rather than having a general metric which induces the topology.